# False cfheader error

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Every time a page on the site is visited I am getting the error message:

> ColdFusion was unable to add the header you specified to the output stream. This is probably because you have already used a cfflush tag in your template or buffered output is turned off.

But, the header is being added.  The line that is causing the error is `<cfheader name="Content-Encoding" value="gzip">`.  If I remove the line then I don't get an error, but gibberish is displayed because the gzip is not decompressed.

I am not using any cfflush tags on the site.  I also saw a suggestion that cftimer tags could cause problems, but I am not using any of those either.

Comment: Please post a minimal (!) but complete (!) sample of CF code that reproduces the error. (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am wondering why the gzip setting is being done via ColdFusion as opposed to the web server. I also wonder what what server is being used

Comment: See also: [cf10 unable to add text to HTML Head](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17516757/3524344)

Answer (score 1):

You can also get this error if your resulting HTTP output is larger than your output buffer.

Check the "Maximum Output Buffer size" setting in CF Administrator and compare that to the size of your output.